# How to get DataGridEditAction.cancel

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, events, datagrid

Checking the datagrid example here 
http://www.silverlight.net/content/samples/sl4/toolkitcontrolsamples/run/default.html 
see the datagrid section

It says that if escape is it twice it will trigger to exit the editing of a row. I always have a datagrid where the user can edit a row but right now the user cannot cancel an edit how can I get the row to exit with the cancel attribute ?

My handler

```
    void RoutingPolicyGrid_RowEditEnded(object sender, DataGridRowEditEndedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.EditAction == DataGridEditAction.Commit)
        {

        }
        else //DatagridEditAction.Cancel
        {

        }
    }
```

Just to add here if I do it manually like the following the datagrid still triggers the RowEditEnded with the commit action this means it gets executed twice with the code below

```
    private void RoutingPolicyGrid_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Escape)
            this.RoutingPolicyGrid_RowEditEnded(sender, new DataGridRowEditEndedEventArgs(null, DataGridEditAction.Cancel));
    }
```

Comment: The datagrid implements the handler for you so I'm confused as to what you're trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to use the built-in mechanism to gracefully exit the Datagridrow edition.

Comment: Sorry, still not clear. If hitting esc twice cancels the edit, what are you trying to handle gracefully?

Comment: I am trying to be able to leave the row_edit mode of the datagrid by triggering the DatagridEditAction.Cancel. Whatever I do I always end up with DatagridEditAction.Commit. What I mean by gracefully handling it is that I would like to be able to use the built-in feature and not have to manually catch when the user enters the escape key. Thx for you reply hopefully I made it slightly clearer for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at the following link. The IEditable interface has to be implemented in order to be able to revert back the edition of a row and to trigger the cancel action.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.canceledit%28VS.95%29.aspx